# AWS Device Farm - Not a file or directory for cucumber features path

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, aws-device-farm

I am trying to run our app tests in device farm but I am getting an error saying it cannot find the features. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: /tmp/scratchktFI9V.scratch/test-packagehFUzci/src/test/resources/features`

I have got the example repo and app running and passing as per [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/testing-mobile-apps-with-cucumber-and-appium-through-testng-on-aws-device-farm/) which is all great but when running our own I get this error.

I noticed the example tests uses `classpath` in the features path but when i try this i just get `Not a file or directory: /tmp/scratchRlueAN.scratch/test-packageMMRQh4/classpath`

These are my cucumber options:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {"@Login"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "steps"
)
```

What should I set this as in my own tests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `classpath:`. Note the colon at the end.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as OP mentioned. I'm not sure where i have to add `classpath:`. can you please help